# Returning multiple lists from one SQLAlchemy query organized by a dict attribute FLASK

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a python function that receives a list of all **VolunteerReports** from a DB and then organizes them into separate lists based on their "report_category", and returns one dict with many lists inside.

**my current function:**

```
def get_volunteer_reports_for_client(volunteer_id, client_id):
    reports_obj = {}

    volunteer_reports = db_session.query(VolunteerReport).filter(
        VolunteerReport.volunteer_id == volunteer_id, \
            VolunteerReport.client_id == client_id).all()

    if not volunteer_reports:
        return []

    res = [volunteer_report_schema.dump(volunteer_report) for volunteer_report in volunteer_reports]

    for r in res:
        reports_obj[r['report_category']] = [r]

    return reports_obj
```

**res** returns a list that looks like so:

```
[
    {
        "client_id": 24,
        "created_at": "2022-02-10 16:41:52.538363",
        "id": 1,
        "report": "This is the first report",
        "report_category": "Client Assigned",
        "volunteer_id": 23
    },
    {
        "client_id": 24,
        "created_at": "2022-02-10 16:41:52.623236",
        "id": 2,
        "report": "This is the SECOND report",
        "report_category": "Client Assigned",
        "volunteer_id": 23
    },
    {
        "client_id": 24,
        "created_at": "2022-02-10 16:41:59.493851",
        "id": 3,
        "report": "This is the THIRD report",
        "report_category": "Fulfilled The Need",
        "volunteer_id": 23
    },
    {
        "client_id": 24,
        "created_at": "2022-02-10 16:43:06.364411",
        "id": 4,
        "report": "This is the FOURTH report",
        "report_category": "Fulfilled The Need",
        "volunteer_id": 23
    }
]
```

**reports_obj** currents returns this:

```
{
    "Client Assigned": [
        {
            "client_id": 24,
            "created_at": "2022-02-10 16:41:52.623236",
            "id": 2,
            "report": "This is the SECOND report",
            "report_category": "Client Assigned",
            "volunteer_id": 23
        }
    ],
    "Fulfilled The Need": [
        {
            "client_id": 24,
            "created_at": "2022-02-10 16:43:06.364411",
            "id": 4,
            "report": "This is the FOURTH report",
            "report_category": "Fulfilled The Need",
            "volunteer_id": 23
        }
    ]
}
```

At this point, it is omitting some of the entries and only returning the last indexed entry with that "report_category". Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration of the loop you are overwriting the current list of dicts in that category with a new list of `[r]`. You need to append the current dict to the list if the key already exists and otherwise create a new list.

```
for r in res:
    category = r['report_category']
    if category in reports_obj:
        reports_obj[category].append(r)
    else:
        reports_obj[category] = [r]
```